# How to manage n number of user with their folders in aws bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on amazon s3 buckets, i have a n number of users whom data has to be stored on the amazon. i want to give access to those users on their correspondence folders only.

The approach i selected is to use federated users credentials for each user and a policy to that credentials that he can use only his folder with that credentials.

But their is a limit on user management policies in amazon (1000 user policies per aws account). where as i have n number of users .

So please give me the best solution for n number of users for accessing amazon bucket/folders for back up and restore.

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily handled it by using temporary security credentials for accessing user's bucket for every

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenDotNet.html

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put rules for all users in single policy?

[Bucket policy examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: hi Thanks For reply! no I didn't actually i am new to amazon so can you share any helpful link or example